# Mistaken name on domestic flight in India

Tags: air-travel, india, paperwork

I booked husband's name by mistake as Manoj pm, when actually it is Manoj c m. Can I travel on domestic flight with this small mistake ?

Comment: Related: [Can I board a domestic flight in India if the name on the ticket is longer than the name in my ID card?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53791/can-i-board-a-domestic-flight-in-india-if-the-name-on-the-ticket-is-longer-than)

Comment: Answer: It depends on the airline and how big the error is. Some are known for insisting on a formal name change of the ticket (which costs money). In your case, there are only two characters difference (or does "c m" hide more complex words?) , so they *may* be OK with it - it is better to check that with the airline, though.

Comment: As people note - it varies. In 2014 I flew Puna-Agra with some friends. One person had a minor mistake in name details and they insisted that it was changed and charged a significant amount to do so - and took long enough to do so that they had to catch a later flight. SO you need to check in advance in each case.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, some airlines permit a one-letter spelling correction (e.g. see http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/india-based-airlines/1510058-name-spelt-wrong.html - "Under the IATA rules applicable to Air India, a single-letter transposition should not be a problem" - although I could not find an actual IATA reference). However, you should contact the airline as soon as possible - do not wait until you get to the airport!

Comment: In India, you need to show proof of a flight + ID to the security guards before you're even allowed into the airport to get to the airline counter. That could be an additional issue for the OP if the ticket isn't fixed up in advance

Comment: I deleted the comments suggesting an illegal behaviour.